Dense Sequences
I'm trying to generalize the following result:

There exists a sequence whose set of subsequential limits is equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

Using the following lemma,

Given a sequence $(p_n)$ with range $E$, $E'$ is equal to the set of limits of subsequences with infinite range.

I am able to derive a relatively simple proof:

$\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so we may arrange it into a sequence of distinct terms $(x_n)$. Since every subsequence would also have infinite range, $L_x = \mathbb{Q}' = \mathbb{R}$.

The result relies primarily on the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is separable, leading me to the following hypothesis:

For every separable metric space $X$, there exists a sequence in $X$ such that its set of subsequential limits is equal to $X$.

However, the proof is not as straightforward, as in many cases only the closure of the countable dense subset is equal to $X$. Before proceeding to tackle this issue, I would really appreciate to know whether the result is correct.
Edit: Here is one such special case. Consider $\mathbb{Z}$, which is trivially separable. But following the same argument wouldn't work, as any infinite subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ has no limit points.

The statement is true for any separable metric space.

Any space with a countable basis has a dense subset that is countable.

consider $\mathbb{Z}$, which is trivially separable. But following the same argument wouldn't work, as it has no limit points.

What you have to do in the case of $\mathbb Z$ is consider a  sequence in which each integer is repeated inifintely many times.

Here is a proof of the general case:
Let $Q$ be a countable dense subset of $X$, enumerated in a sequence $(q_n)$. We construct a sequence $(x_n)$ such that
\begin{align*}
        x_1 &= q_1, \\
        x_2 &= q_1, x_3 = q_2, \\
        x_4 &= q_1, x_5 = q_2, x_6 = q_3, \\
        &\vdots
    \end{align*}
By the given lemma, $Q' \subseteq L_x$. As for each $k$, there are infinitely many $q_k$ in $(x_n)$, one also has $Q \subseteq L_x$. Hence $\overline{Q} \subseteq L_x \implies L_x = X$, as required.
